# Calculating Volume of sphere

Tags: python

```
pi=22/7
rad3 = float(input("Enter the radius of the circle: "))
print("\n")
float(print (4/3)* pi *rad3**3)
```

Im not sure what is wrong with my code

Answer (score 1):

You are printing inside a float cast. That `print(4/3)` returns a None value, which cannot obviously be multiplied with a float value (pi variable). Maybe you wanted to do `print(float((4/3) * pi * rad3 ** 3))`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
pi=22/7
rad = float(input("Enter the radius of the circle: "))
print("\n")
V= 4.0/3.0*pi*rad**3
print ("Volume is", V)
```

Comment: print(4/3) returns None, I don't see how it fits in multiplication.